# MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I try to get current depth of MQ queue with Java application. I use the following code:

```
int depth = 0;
MQQueueManager qMgr; // define a queue manager object
String mqHost = "host";
String mqPort = "1416";
String mqChannel = "chan";
String mqQMgr = "mgr";
String mqQueue = "q";

MQEnvironment.hostname = mqHost;
MQEnvironment.port = Integer.valueOf(mqPort).intValue();
MQEnvironment.channel = mqChannel;
MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES); //tried to remove this line - didn't help
qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqQMgr);
int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED;
//tried to use int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE - didn't help
MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(mqQueue, openOptions);
depth = destQueue.getCurrentDepth();
```

But I get error

> "com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'"

on line `MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(mqQueue, openOptions)`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: reason 2085 is "Unknown Object Name" - The queue manager you're trying to access may not be named "mgr", or the queue may not be named "q", or the channel may not be named "chan". In any case, *something* you're asking for doesn't exist.

Comment: Queue names in IBM MQ are case-sensitive.  "q" != "Q".  Also, you should not use the MQEnvironment class as it is not thread-safe.  Put your connection properties in a HashTable and pass it to the MQQueueManager class.  See my previous post here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084185/mq-source-in-spark-structured-streaming/51091481#51091481

Comment: P.S. you might find this answer helpful when you don't know what the 2000+ number means https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67597818/mqje001-completion-code-2-reason-2nnn