# MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2nnn'

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I got an error like:-

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2nnn'
```

from my Java application. How can I discover what the 2000+ number means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look up an MQ Reason code (normally in the range 2000 - 2999) use the `mqrc` tool that comes with IBM MQ on the distributed platforms.

From the command line type:-

```
mqrc 2085
```

and see a response like:-

```
2085  0x00000825  MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME
```

The constant name, in this case `MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME`, may be enough to tell you what this number means, especially if you have perhaps seen it before. If you need more information, go to the [IBM Docs for MQ](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest) and look up either the number or the constant name.

**Handy Hint**

If you put the number and then the word 'explanation' in the search bar in the [IBM Docs for MQ](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest), you will find that the first result is always the one you want.

[image: IBM Docs search bar]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output both the reason code and the associated reason code text in your Java application then you would do:

```
try
{
}
catch (MQException e)
{
   System.err.println("CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode + " [" + MQConstants.lookup(e.reasonCode, "MQRC_.*") + "]" );
}
```

If you are looking for a full description of the reason code then go to the following page in the MQ Knowledge Center: https://www.ibm.com/docs/fr/ibm-mq/latest?topic=codes-api-reason